# Как не вводить каждый раз логин и пароль при использовании git на Linux Mint

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, linux-mint

Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить git так, чтобы мне не надо было постоянно вводить логин и пароль. Сам проект на nestjs, репозиторий в gitlab. Работаю через VS Code на Linux Mint.
Извиняюсь заранее за возможно очень простой вопрос, но в интернете ничего работающего пока не нашёл

Comment: Сделайте себе ssh ключи и пропишите их в конфиге ssh.

Comment: Пара вопросов: а ты гитом пользуешься в терминале?  А в VS разве нет тулзы работы с гитом?

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я пользуюсь гитом через инструменты VS Code, но VS Code запрашивает логин и пароль при каждой синхронизации, коммите и т.п

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать выполнить в терминале команду:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Если на какое-то конкретное время:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А нет, не работает, я ошибся

Comment: Не работает, просто я забыл, что коммит сам по себе без синхронизации не требует

Comment: Что значит фраза *"коммит сам по себе без синхронизации не требует"*?

Comment: То, что в VS Code они локальные, пока ты не запустишь синхронизацию

Comment: А, стоп... Оно внезапно с ничего начало работать только что... ладно

Comment: Ну, раз работает, то снова спасибо